# mod_rewrite match part of query string wherever it occurs

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In moving a client to SEO friendly URLs I added a number of rewrite rules that work very well as long at the query string is an exact match.  Here is one:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/index.php/site/show$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^activeshow=32118028$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/shows/someshow/   [R=301,L]
```

What I have found is that newsletters etc which add to the query string do not match.  How do I re-phrase this to match activeshow=32118028 anywhere in the query string?

Comment: remove the `^` and `$`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/index.php/site/show$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   (^|&)activeshow=32118028(&|$)
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://foo.com/shows/someshow/   [R=301,L]
```